# Do Engines Contradict Conservation of Angular Momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, torque

When I start the engine in my car and the crankshaft starts rotating, where does the opposite angular momentum hide?

Is it the air that gets sucked in and out of the engine? But then what if I had an electric engine instead? Is the car actually applying torque to the Earth beneath it and the corresponding angular acceleration  can simply not be seen due to the relatively large mass of the Earth?

Comment: Why should the angular momentum be conserved? This could only be true if $\dot{L}(t) = 0 = M(t)$. If you start the motor you apply a force to the system and so $M(t) \neq 0$.

Comment: conservation of momentum is for the *whole* system: earth+vehicle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the car actually applying torque to the earth beneath it and the corresponding angular acceleration can simply not be seen due to the relatively large mass of the Earth?

Yes. There's nothing else happening.